# Problema restricciones xsd de un xml

Tags: xml, xsd

estoy realizando un curso (donde el profesor no explica una ....) y llevo días intentando sacar restricción de un elemento que tiene un atributo en su interior. soy nuevo esto y casi no  me entero mucho.
seria posible una ayuda.

Esto es lo que pide: La distancia es un número mayor de 0. Es necesario que la distancia tenga un atributo unidad que indica la unidad en forma de cadena.

```
  <xs:element name="distancia">
    
    <xs:complexType>
        
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:integer">  
                <!-- ** final restriction del atributo unidad  --><!-- **EJERC 7.4-->    
                <xs:attribute name="unidad" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN"><!-- ** EN CADENA, solo llego hacer esto y no se si esta bien  -->
                           
                           
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
                <!-- **FIN EJERC 7.4--> 
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando necesitas crear un tipo que incluye un elemento y sus atributos, el tipo del atributo no s epuede definir inline y  debes crear su definicion por aparte. Algo así:

```
  <xs:attribute name="unidad" use="required" type="xs:NMTOKEN" />
  <xs:element name="distancia">

   <xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:integer"> 
           <xs:attribute ref="unidad" /> 
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```